# How to avoid passing argument in URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, parameter-passing

Hi professionals have a good day.

I am new to this Codeigniter framework.

**Question 1:** how to avoid passing argument in url or is there any other option like using dummy value or default value instead of passing original value?

**Example :** Currently i have like this

`http://localhost/manage?keyword1=SAP&keyword2=LAB`

but i want it to be like this

```
http://localhost/manage?keyword1=XXX&keyword2=YYY
```

**Question 2:** i have seen  some example, in that they are using remap function to accomplish this task but i didnt get how ***remap*** work . is this right way do to?

please give your suggestion and tell me the right way and sorry it may be a silly question but i searched lot i didnt anything . thanks in advance

Comment: is `manage` controller name?

Comment: @kumar_v yes.manage is controller name

Comment: then you can set default parameters in your index function.

Comment: sorry to ask how to do that plz give me any examples...

Comment: i think you are asking to mask the url parameter values?

Comment: @kumar yes you are right..

Comment: @kumar is there any right way to do that sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Codeignitor you have to pass like this `http://localhost/manage/controller/method/xxx/yyy`

then in controller

```
function method ( $x , $y )
{
  echo $x;
  echo $y;
}
```

Comment: if $x=SAP and $y=LAB it will be like this http://localhost/manage/controller/method/SAP/LAB but i want it to be like this http://localhost/manage/controller/method/xxx/yyy.. i want to hide original argument

Comment: then you pass parameters encoded and then decode into method

Comment: yes pass parameters like that it depends on you how to pass the parameters through $_get or $_post. In $_post you don't need to define paramters

Comment: i thought about that..k let me apply that

Answer (score 1):

```
function somefunction ($param1 = null, $param2 = null)
{



}
```

if the params are not passed, then it will have the default values `null`, but if the arguments are passed then you could handle them like this:

```
function somefunction ($param1 = null, $param2 = null)
{
   $param1 = intval($param1) //if you want it to be int
   $param2 = floatval($param2) //if you want it to be float


}
```

if you want to change the parameters visually in the browser, then just redirect it like this:

```
function somefunction ($param1 = null, $param2 = null)
{
   if($param1 == null || $param2 == null)
  {
      $param1 = 'XXX'; //put any value you want by your logic
      $param2 = 'YYY'; //put any value you want by your logic
      header("Location: http://localhost/manager/somefunction/".$param1.'/'.$param2);
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter, there is a library called 'session'. In this library there is a functionality called flashdata. This acts just like a $_POST method, however it does not require a form.

Example:
To set a variable in flashdata:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('example', $variable1);
```

'example' is the name of your flashdata and $variable is what it's storing.

To access your data on the next page:

```
$variable2 = $this->session->flashdata('example');
```

$variable2 will then equal whatever you set $variable1 as in the previous page.

Hope this helps! Just an alternative to passing an argument through the URL.